# Program is not printing appropriate value

Tags: c++

[image]This is my code.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int num;

    cout<<"Enter the no."<<endl;

    cin>>num;

    int i;

    for(int i=2;i<num;i++){
        if(num%i==0){
            cout<<"It is not a prime number."<<endl;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(i==num)
    {
        cout<<"It is a prime number."<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Theoretically it has to print it is a prime number when a prime number is given as a input, but it is not doing that.
I have attached the picture please refer to it.

Comment: You have 2 different `i`. Change the loop to `for(i=2;i<num;i++){ ... }`

Comment: Aside from the two different `i` thing, the logic is backward.

Comment: Yes i have made the logic changes but it is still not working

Comment: churill please make your point clear i am nbot getting it

Comment: @SparshKarna You declare the first `int i;` right before the loop. Inside the loop you declare the second `i`: `for(int i=2;i<num;i++){` The loop will only modify the second `i`, not the first one. That's called [variable shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing). Later the `if(i==num)` will see only the first `i` that was never initialized and thus contains a garbage value.

Comment: Why do you divide by even numbers, there are no prime numbers that are even, apart from 2

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you can do.
First declare a variable(for ex- var, flag etc.). [flag=0]
Also in your code: the for loop it shold be like this:

```
 for(i=2;i<=num/2;i++)
    {
       if(num%i==0)
       {
           cout<<"Number is not prime.";
           flag=1;
        }
     }`
```

Also it is not `if(i==num)`

It is:

```
if(flag==0)
 {
    cout<<"Number is prime.";
 }
```

Comment: There's no need to declare `i` outside the for loop if you're replacing the check with a flag. Why have you removed the `break`?

Comment: Oh no I forgot. break is necessary

Answer (score 0):

You have two different variables named i. One is declared in the for loop and the other is declared before the loop.
The i in the for loop is a local variable. It means it's only used in the loop, after this i is cleaned.
So when you test "i==nmb", it's test the first i variable with nmb. But your first i is declared but not initialized so this condition will never execute because i have no value.
One solution is to use flags as @advait dandekar do